# how to share multifunction printers over network

Tags: windows-home-server, print-server

I'm planing to set up a home network using windows home server and 2 other PCs and I would like to share my multifunction printer over the network (Canon Pixma MP450).

The printer has scanner and card reader, I know how to share the printer but how do I share the scanner and the card reader?

this is my setup

- 1 Pc Win 7 ultimate x64
- 1 laptop Win 7 home premium x64
- 1 server Win home server x86 <-- where the multifunction printer is connected by usb

thanks

UPDATE: I just found out about usb sharing over network, anyone has experience with this?
examples 
http://www.usb-over-network.com/
http://www.intellidriver.com/products_1.16.html

Comment: Questions about your home network really belong on superuser.  The question will be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

You normally can't share the multiple functions, only the printing ability. Unless you get a (very expensive) printer that is meant to share functions over a network.

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't appear like that multifunction printers was designed from network usage there may be no way to share the other other features.  You mention it is attached to a Windows Home Server, so you should be able to just RDP to the WHS box and run the software from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try scanner virtualization from FabulaTech. It allows redirecting scanners into RDP or Citrix session, supports both TWAIN and WIA and doesn't require scanner drivers to be installed on the server.

http://www.scanner-for-remote-desktop.com/